# pass video source to other element's ng-init in angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs, hidden-field, angular-services, angularjs-ng-init

> How can i can pass my video source(srcVideo) to ng-init in videoDetailsform.VideoUrl?
>
> ### Video.html

```
<input ng-model="videoDetailsform.title" class="form-control input-default" ng-modal="form.vid_Title"   placeholder="Video Title." ng-init="videoDetailsform.title=''">
<video  placeholder="Drop Video Here" width="100%" ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="objectDropped()" id="myVideo" >
   <source id="mp4Source" ng-src={{srcVideo}} type="video/mp4">
   <source id="webmSource" ng-src={{srcVideo}} type="video/Webm">    
</video>

<input type="hidden" ng-model="videoDetailsform.title" ng-init="videoDetailsform.title='{{form.vid_Title}}'">   
<input type="hidden" ng-model="videoDetailsform.VideoUrl" ng-init="videoDetailsform.VideoUrl=srcVideo">
```

> ### VideoController.js
>
> In this file i am pushing all video information to **videoCs['VideoDetails']** and using **myService.js** method *createJsonFormatter()* to save it.

```
videoCs['VideoDetails'] = [];
$scope.saveDraft = function(){
    videoCs['VideoDetails'].push($scope.videoDetailsform);
    saveData.createJsonFormatter(JSON.stringify(videoCs));
};
```

> ### myService.js

```
videoCourseApp.service('saveData', function(fileSystem){
this.createJsonFormatter = function(data){

    console.log(data);
    var txtFileName = "videos.json";
    fileSystem.writeText(txtFileName, data).then(function(fs) {
        console.log('success');
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
};
});
```

> I am getting data from input type but not able to fetch video source.

Comment: Hard to give a helpful advice without related information. What's the sense in creating a hidden field? New to AngularJS? In any case `$scope.videoDetailsform.VideoUrl` is accessible in your controller and you can do assignment `$scope.videoDetailsform.VideoUrl = $scope.srcVideo`. BTW correct syntax for `ng-init` would be `ng-init="videoDetailsform.VideoUrl=srcVideo"`. `ng-init` expects a JS expression that would be executed in context of `$scope`

Comment: I am trying to save _srcVideo_ to JSON. First I am dropping any video to video panel which is setting _srcVideo_. I am using **videoDetailsform** to push all information related to video in it, eg, _videoDetailsform.topic_, _videoDetailsform.time_, _videoDetailsform.vidUrl_, etc. Because all are text fields except **video tag** and for text fields i am passing data using ng-modal but for video tag i dont find any way to do it.

Comment: Please share the code you mentioned for clearer understanding